# Ionic v2 Button text in caps

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

In my ionic v2 app is a button, no matter which text I type in, it's always capitalized. I don't want to add css-utilities, because i have mixed lower and upper case words.

Here is my code:

```
<button ion-button large block color="danger" (click)="openPage($event, 0)">
    This is my test Text.
</button>
```

I've tried to remove all properties from the button tag, but that did not worked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems the button has **text-transform** set to **uppercase** in **CSS**. Add the following **CSS** to your button: `text-transform: none;` to override the **CSS** property set.

Your code becomes something like this:

```
<button ion-button large block color="danger" style="text-transform: none;" (click)="openPage($event, 0)">
    This is my test Text.
</button>
```

For more information on the **text-transform** property
[CSS text-transform Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp)

Comment: thanks, that worked, i've set it globally in the app.scss file for all buttons.

Comment: @tom_tom Glad I could help, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

Put the following in the variables.scss

```
    $button-md-text-transform: none;
```

By default, the value is uppercase for Android platform. Change it to none. This will be applied to every button in your app.

Comment: This is a better answer for the question, please avoid using inline style in any scenario if it's possible.

Comment: A very neat solution.

Comment: For ios you just change the md to ios and it will work also. Sometimes it takes inspecting the html elements to see the exact class the style is under.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Platform Specific Styles](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/platform-specific-styles/) to style the buttons in your application.

Ionic2 has four platforms:

1. ios: Viewing on an iPhone or iPad, **mode** = 'ios'.
2. android: Viewing on any android device, **mode** = 'md'.
3. windows: Viewing on any windows device, **mode** = 'wp'.
4. core: Any platform that doesn't fit any of the above platforms will use the Material Design styles, **mode** = 'md'.

---

**Overriding the Mode Styles.**
You can use the class that is applied to the body to override specific properties in mode components. In this case you would like to override the button style to have no text transform.

Place the code down here in the variables.scss file. Scroll down untill you see the section "App iOS Variables" or "App Material Design Variables"

```
// Style Android buttons
.md button {
  text-transform: none;
}

// Style iOS buttons
.ios button {
  text-transform: none;
}

// Style Windows Phone buttons
.wp button {
  text-transform: none;
}
```

---

More about theming your app: [Theming your Ionic App](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/theming-your-app/) 
More about CSS text-transform property: [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp)

Answer (score 4):

Change your template as below:

```
<button class="removeTextTransform" ion-button large block color="danger" (click)="openPage($event, 0)">
    This is my test Text.
</button>
```

Add following code in your `app.scss`:

```
.removeTextTransform {
  text-transform: none;
}
```

Use `removeTextTransform` class whenever you want to remove text transform from your ionic button.

Answer (score 1):

> add **text-capitalize** in your button like this

```
<button ion-button text-capitalize (click)="openPage($event, 0)">This is my test Text.</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

To set it globally add

```
.button {
   text-transform: none;
 }
```

Inside `global.scss`

Answer (score 0):

**For IONIC 4**

Add `text-capitalize="false"` to your button.

Eg:

```
<ion-button text-capitalize="false" shape="round">Click</ion-button>
```